# How can i pull current opportunity data and send to external third party service from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, integration, apex, callouts

I want to add a custom button on opportunity item and on click of it will fetch the opportunity contract details and send it to third party service. I read about the rest callout by which we can make the third party api call after register it on Remote Site Settings But how can we include the current opportunity items details with it?

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setMethod(method);
request.setEndpoint(endpoint);

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

Comment: There is not enough information here.  You'll most likely need a visualforce page and controller that will load the opportunity and then format the request body.  The way the request is created/formatted and sent will be based on the endpoint that you are sending the information.  Most likely you will need to set multiple headers on the request as I'm sure your third parting will have some security involved.

Comment: Have a  look at [External Services + Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/external-services)